# javascript don't read src type always an error been shown up

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the part of javascript bugged

```
function addCartClicked (event) {
    var button = event.target;
    var shopProducts = button.parentElement;
    var title = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("product-name")[0].innerText;
    var price = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText;
    var productImg = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("product-image")[0].src;

    console.log(title, price, productImg);
  }
```

and this is the HTML part

```
<section class="projects" id="section">
<center><h1 class="ourpr">OUR PRODUCTS:</h1></center>
<div class="content">
<li>
<div class="project-card">
<img src="C:\Users\MSI\Documents\INFO\ex4 serie html\TOPG\capolista.png" alt="" class="product-        image" style="width: 360px; height: 348px;">
<div class="project-info">
<strong class="project-title"> <a class="product-name">makrouna fil</a> <a class="price">10$    </a><a class="addcart" align="center">Add to Cart</a>  </strong> </div>
</div>
 </li>
```

an error always showd up :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'src')

even when i put `.innerText` it's still the same idk why

i tried to replace it with innerText still the same
and i tried to put it without "."

```
var productImg = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("product-image")[0])
```

it just show the price and the name no image shown

Comment: You can't use local pathnames as `src`. It has to be a URL.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It doesn't say the property is undefined, it says the value you're trying to read the property of is undefined. So changing the property won't fix it.

Comment: What button is the `addCartClicked` used as the vent listener for.

Comment: Your image has a class of `product-        image`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Get rid of those unwanted spaces in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the spaces from the `img` class from:

```html
<img src="C:\Users\MSI\Documents\INFO\ex4 serie html\TOPG\capolista.png" alt="" class="product-        image" style="width: 360px; height: 348px;">
```

to

```html
<img src="C:\Users\MSI\Documents\INFO\ex4 serie html\TOPG\capolista.png" alt="" class="product-image" style="width: 360px; height: 348px;">
```

```js
function addCartClicked(event) {
    var button=event.target;
    var shopProducts=button.parentElement;
    var title=shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("product-name")[0].innerText;
    var price=shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText;
    var productImg=shopProducts.getElementsByClassName("product-image")[0].src;

    console.log(title, price, productImg);
}
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = addCartClicked;
```

```html
<section class="projects" id="section">
    <center>
        <h1 class="ourpr">OUR PRODUCTS:</h1>
    </center>
    <div class="content">
        <li>
            <div class="project-card">
                <img src="C:\Users\MSI\Documents\INFO\ex4 serie html\TOPG\capolista.png" alt="" class="product-image" style="width: 360px; height: 348px;">
                <div class="project-info">
                    <strong class="project-title"> <a class="product-name">makrouna fil</a> <a class="price">10$    </a><a class="addcart" align="center">Add to Cart</a>  </strong> </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>
</section>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn').onclick = addCartClicked;` suffices. No need for the anonymous function.

Answer (score -1):

Please try by removing the space of classname from `<img>` tag as `class="product-image"`. Don't add unwanted spaces, it's not a good practice.